# Is it possible to use onClick with an Image in MSIE 10?

Tags: jsp

I'm trying to trigger a javaScript call when someone clicks on an image.

```
<img id="chartImg" oncopy="handleCopyEvent();" border=0 width=1425 height=660 alt="chart" 
 src="<%=imagePath %>" onDblClick="mouseClickHandler(event.type);" usemap="#main" 
 onClick="mouseClickHandler(event.type);">
```

This will not working in  I.E 10 but working fine in I.E 9 and below versions of I.E.Please

suggest the proper solution.I am waiting for your response.

Answer (score 0):

ther is no need to include `href="javascript:void(0)"` just remove `href` tag

Comment: but my ie 10 custom level tab disbled.

Comment: But anyway it is working fine IE 9 and below the problem is with ie 10 only

Comment: eventhough i tried with your previous answer it is not working

Comment: try to use jquery  $("#chartImg").click(function(event){ alert("hi")})

Comment: no john we have to use only javascript in my project.if i use jquery means i have add so many libraries